# How to use wildcards in SET statement SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, set, wildcard

I am building a SQL report that has multiple variables that will eventually be set up in SSRS for end users. For my testing purposes in SQL Server, I have declared several variables and now want to use the SET statement to assign values. Some of the variables have a specific value assigned and for others, I just want to use a wildcard. I've tried using `%` and `'%'`, but I get syntax errors. I am working in SQL Server 2008 R2.

Here are my `DECLARE` and `SET` statements:

```
declare @start datetime
declare @end datetime
declare @Emp# varchar
declare @Posn varchar
declare @GL# varchar
declare @HrType varchar
declare @ProdCode varchar
declare @WComp varchar

set @start = '07/01/2015'
set @end = '07/31/2015'
set @Emp# = '068'
set @Posn = %
set @GL# = %
set @HrType = %
set @ProdCode = %
set @WComp = %
```

I am a self-taught newbie, but I've reviewed all of the information I could find in stackoverflow and in Google.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have a value you want assigned, don't `SET` a value for the variables.

You do not need an initial value if you populate the variable later on in your query.

If you want to capture all values using this parameter, then you are doing it incorrectly.

You could set your parameter to **ALL**. The use your parameter in a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE (ProdCode = @ProdCode OR @ProdCode = 'ALL')
```

Comment: My ultimate goal is that in SSRS, an end user will be able to open this report up, select any one or multiples or all of each of the parameters.  Example:  start = '10/01/2015', end = '10/31/2015', Posn = ALL, Emp# = '068',  GL# = ALL, HrType = All, ProdCode = 'Productive Hrs Only', WComp - ALL.  The idea being a very robust set of parameters that will be as broad or as narrow as the user needs.

Comment: I know how to set that up in SSRS.  But the problem is I want to test the SQL first in MS SQL Server Management Studios, so I was trying to replicate some conditions someone might use to run a report.

Comment: So is the answer I just comment out any parameters that I don't want to set to a specific value while testing in SQL and not worry about the wildcard?  AND comment the WHERE clause line items.  :)

Comment: Yes - you can declare your parameter to test your query but when you put it in SSRS you'll use the parameter in your WHERE but don't declare it. It will get the parameter value from SSRS mapped on the PARAMETER tab of the Dataset.

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  I have created the parameters in SSRS and they are working at this time.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's a varchar. Use single quotes like you always would:

```
set @Posn = '%'
```

You then need to make sure you're using `LIKE` instead of `=` in your comparisons.

If that doesn't work, your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you, but when I use single quotes, I get no results at all.  No errors, but also no results.

Comment: Can't help with that until you show the SELECT query.

Comment: I believe I was over-thinking this.  I have chosen to just comment out any WHERE statements and the related parameters for testing purposes in SQL.  Thank you for your information.